# Making custom type array convertible in Swift

Tags: swift, casting

Let's assume we have a custom type given by

```
struct S {
    let value_1: UInt = 1
    let value_2: UInt = 2
}
```

and I want to create a `Double` array (e.g. [1.0, 2.0]) using a cast:

```
let s = S()
let a = s as Array<Double> // fails obviously
```

The final goal is to call

```
func aMethod(array: [Double]) { ... }
```

in a convient way:

```
let s = S()
aMethod(s)
```

My first idea was to use

```
extension S {
    // but how to continue here?
}
```

Any ideas of solving this in an elegant way without a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `array` property to the Struct, for example:

```
struct S {
    let value_1: UInt = 1
    let value_2: UInt = 2
    var array: [UInt] {
        return [value_1, value_2]
    }
}

let s = S()
let a = s.array  // [1, 2]
```

An extension also works:

```
struct S {
    let value_1: UInt = 1
    let value_2: UInt = 2
}

extension S {
    var array: [UInt] {
        return [value_1, value_2]
    }
}

let s = S()
let a = s.array  // [1, 2]
```

And why not a protocol:

```
protocol HasArray {
    var value_1: UInt { get }
    var value_2: UInt { get }
    var array: [UInt] { get }
}

extension HasArray {
    var array: [UInt] {
        return [value_1, value_2]
    }
}

struct S: HasArray {
    let value_1: UInt = 1
    let value_2: UInt = 2
}

let s = S()
let a = s.array  // [1, 2]
```

Comment: I assume there is no way for `methodExpectingADoubleArray(s)`, because there is no implicit conversion in Swift, right?

Comment: Mm, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean duck typing like in Ruby?

Comment: Actually no, more in the direction of implicit conversion. But I think this is not possible, right?

Comment: Indeed, I think doing it exactly how you want isn't possible in Swift.